# Is there any way to catch a "delete account" event from settings in Android?

Tags: android, push-notification, push, accountmanager, accounts

I'm developing an application synchronized with a server. This server generate push notifications to the mobile. It's based on custom multi-accounts, so, if the user logout the application, the account won't be deleted, he will be redirected to a list with all accounts.

If the user delete an account, the server must know this action because it need to stop to send push notifications.

Comment: I am not sure about event but you can delete account using `AccountManager`

Comment: that's true, but I need to catch the event of delete from settings